# Is there a fold like algorithm in std (or failing that: boost) available?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, fold, accumulate

A very simpel example is multiplication - suppose I have a vector:

```
std::vector<int> ints = {1,2,3,4};
```

With a naive approach I can just use `std::accumulate` (or `std::reduce`) and it looks like this:

```
int result = std::accumulate(ints.begin(), ints.end(), int{}, [](const int &a, const int &b){return a*b;});
```

but since the initial value is zero - the result becomes zero as well (For this specific case, one way I could fix it is by putting a '1' as initial).

I would rather use an algorithm that does the above but without an initial value 'side-effect' (ie. just multiply the numbers in vector).

A similar problem is often encountered within string handling where a delimiter must be inserted **between** elements.

Comment: You mean somenthing like [`reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce)?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca reduce has the same issue.

Comment: You could use `accumulate(v.begin()+1, v.end(), v[0])`, but ensure that v.size() >0

Comment: @ThomasLang that would also fix it yes

Comment: Indeed, this question boils down to "what should it return for an empty range". `std::accumulate` sidesteps this by requiring an initial argument.

Comment: Ummm... Make the initial value 1? A.k.a. "`int{1}`". Seems too obvious...

Comment: imho `accumulate` is made for exactly this use case. Note that `*` is not that different from `+` in that you have to use the "neutral element" (not sure about the correct english term) as initial value. It just happens that the neutral element of `+` is `0` while for `*` it is `1.0`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The OP literally said that.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Well, using `1.0` would give you different results (potentially). Use `1` for ints ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh right, now I get the point. Something doesnt need the initial value would really be a different algorithm

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Not really it's just a specific case (range is non-empty) of this one with some rearranged arguments

Comment: When considering string handling (or perhaps ranges in general) - an empty range is usually fine - and can just return an empty string (or empty container) - for other cases im less certain on what it would mean..

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that is called `id` which is 0 for addition, 1 for multiplication and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about can be reframed as a generalisation of `accumulate` over the last *N-1* elements of your range, with the 1st element being the initial value.

So you can just write:

```
std::accumulate(std::next(std::begin(ints)), std::end(ints), *std::begin(ints), OP);
```

You have to assume that `ints` is non-empty, though, which raises my main point: what should a hypothetical standard function return when the range is empty? Should its results simply be undefined? Is that sensible?

> *(current draft)* [`237)`](http://eel.is/c++draft/accumulate#footnote-237) `accumulate` is similar to the APL reduction operator and Common Lisp reduce function, but it avoids the difficulty of defining the result of reduction on an empty sequence by always requiring an initial value

Accumulate sidesteps this issue *and* provides a boatload of flexibility, by doing things the way it does. I think that's a good thing.

Combined with the ability to simply provide an appropriate initial value like `1` for your operation over the whole range, I'm not convinced there's much need for this hypothetical alternative in the standard.

It might also be difficult to come up with *two* names for it that mirror the already-asymmetrically-named "accumulate" and "reduce".

---

```
template <class InputIt, class T, class BinaryOperation>
T fold_if_you_really_want_to(InputIt first, InputIt last, BinaryOperation op)
{
    // UB if range is empty. Whatevs.
    T init = *first;
    return std::accumulate(++first, last, std::move(init), std::move(op));
}
```

…or something like that anyway. Note that this necessarily copies the first element; you could avoid that if you weren't lazy by calling into `std::accumulate` like I did.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Lightness Races in Orbit's answer, consider the case in Haskell:
For cases like you described it (most prominently searching the maximum element in a list), Haskell delivers the functions `foldl1` and `foldr1`, which perform the fold over the collection and implicitly taking the first value as initial value.
Yes, for the empty list this makes no sense, hence for this problem you have to provide a list with at least one element.